# maintain state within div when back or forward button is clicked (html5 pushState)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html5-history

Regarding on html5 pushState, when back button was clicked, url was able to reflect the changes required but div in-within did not able to show the old info, this also applies to forward button.

I am new to this, below is the codes:

**index.php**

```
<button type="button" id="menu-btn-1">Menu 1 (steak)</button>
<button type="button" id="menu-btn-2">Menu 2 (vegan)</button>

<div id="menu-res"></div>

<script src="./index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**res.php**

```
<?php
if($_POST['order'] == "steak"){
    echo "medium rare steak";
}
if($_POST['order'] == "salad"){
    echo "hawaii salad";
}
?>
```

**index.js**

```
function show(input) {
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById("menu-res").innerHTML=null;
            document.getElementById("menu-res").innerHTML=this.responseText;
            //how to maintain state when back/forward button is clicked?                
            history.pushState(this.responseText, null, input);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","res.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    let data = 'order='+input;
    xmlhttp.send(data);
}



window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("menu-btn-1").addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        show("steak");
    });
});

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("menu-btn-2").addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        show("salad");
    });
});

window.addEventListener('popstate', ()=> {
    show("");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the stored "state" you need to use the `popstate` listener to render / process whatever data you have stored in the history stack. Taking much from your original code perhaps the following single-page script will help.

The key to displaying the original content ( which is what I believe was the central point of your issue ) is the use of `setdisplay( e.state )` within the `popstate` listener.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['order'] ) ){
        ob_clean();
        
        switch( $_POST['order'] ){
            case 'steak':
                echo 'Delicious meaty goodness, cooked to perfection on the grill and served with fries';
            break;
            case 'vegan':
                echo 'The food my food eats...';
            break;
            case 'protein':
                echo 'Rather like the Steak menu but greater variety of protein types';
            break;
            case 'carbs':
                echo 'Energy laden pasta and similar to get you through the day/night';
            break;
            case 'salad':
                echo 'Rather like the "Vegan" menu but not as fashionable';
            break;
            case 'seafood':
                echo 'Exquisite delicacies from the World\'s Oceans';
            break;
        }
        
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>History State mangling and manipulation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <button type='button' data-type='menu' name='steak'>Menu 1 (steak)</button>
        <button type='button' data-type='menu' name='vegan'>Menu 2 (vegan)</button>
        <button type='button' data-type='menu' name='protein'>Menu 3 (High Protein)</button>
        <button type='button' data-type='menu' name='carbs'>Menu 4 (Carbs)</button>
        <button type='button' data-type='menu' name='salad'>Menu 5 (Salad)</button>
        <button type='button' data-type='menu' name='seafood'>Menu 6 (Fish & Seafood)</button>
        
        <div id='menu-res'></div>
        
        <script>
            const setdisplay=( text )=>document.getElementById('menu-res').innerHTML=text;
        
            /* delegated event listener to process button clicks */
            document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
                if( e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && e.target.dataset.type=='menu' ){
                    
                    /* Prepare and send AJAX request */
                    let fd=new FormData();
                        fd.set('order',e.target.name);
                        
                    fetch( location.href,{ method:'post', body:fd } )
                        .then(r=>r.text())
                        .then( text=>{
                            /* Set the history state ... whatever you wish to store within reason. */
                            history.pushState( text, `Menu: ${e.target.name} - ${text}`, '?order='+e.target.name );
                            
                            /* display the ajax response */
                            setdisplay( text );
                        })
                        .catch( alert )
                }
            });
            
            /* rebuild HTML display when browser back/forward buttons are clicked. */
            window.addEventListener('popstate',e=>{
                setdisplay( e.state )
            })
        </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```